# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException When I launch edge with IE mode using RemoteWebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to run automated tests on an application that runs only on Edge with IE Mode. To do this, I'm using `selenium-server-4.8.2.jar` to run the standalone server on my remote machine.

In my project, I have the `selenium-java` dependency to the `4.1.3` version.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

On the remote machine (which as of now is `localhost`), I'm running the selenium-server like this:

```
java -"Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Users\abc\Downloads\IEDriverServer_Win32_4.8.1\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar .\selenium-server-4.8.1.jar standalone
```

I have a Java function that has the actual code:

```
public static void runIEWithEdge() throws MalformedURLException {
        String remoteUrl = "http://localhost:4444";

        InternetExplorerOptions edgeOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        edgeOptions.attachToEdgeChrome();
        edgeOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");

        // Create RemoteWebDriver with the EdgeOptions and remote URL
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteUrl), edgeOptions);

        // Navigate to a webpage
        driver.get("http://demo.borland.com/gmopost");

        // Do some automation tasks
        driver.findElement(By.name("bSubmit")).click();



        // Close the browser
        driver.quit();

    }
```

However, when I run this, the browser doesn't launch at all, and I get the following exception from the selenium-server

```
11:02:28.393 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$1] - Unable to create session: Could not start a new session. null
Host info: host: 'YCSLAPTEMP', ip: '192.168.16.118'
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
11:02:28.393 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$1] - org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. null
Host info: host: 'YCSLAPTEMP', ip: '192.168.16.118'
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply(DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:215)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply(DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:69)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.SessionSlot.apply(SessionSlot.java:147)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode.newSession(LocalNode.java:384)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.startSession(LocalDistributor.java:645)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.newSession(LocalDistributor.java:564)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable.handleNewSessionRequest(LocalDistributor.java:818)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable.lambda$run$1(LocalDistributor.java:779)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Not sure how to fix this. But, I tried another way using the `EdgeOptions` instead of `InternetExplorerOptions` like here:

```
 public static void runEdge( String[] args ) throws MalformedURLException {
        String remoteUrl = "http://localhost:4444";

        EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();

        edgeOptions.setCapability("ie.edgechromium", true);
        edgeOptions.setCapability("ie.browserCommandLineArguments", "-ms-edge-legacy-emulation-mode-ie11");

        // Create RemoteWebDriver with the EdgeOptions and remote URL
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteUrl), edgeOptions);

        // Navigate to a webpage
        driver.get("http://demo.borland.com/gmopost");

        driver.findElement(By.name("bSubmit")).click();

        // Do some automation tasks

        // Close the browser
        driver.quit();

    }
```

This launches Edge and the program runs fine, but **doesn't start edge on IE Mode**

I badly want to launch Edge with IE mode on a remote machine. Please help with any ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: Does Edge on IE Mode gets initiated in the localhost?

Comment: If you're asking whether I'm manually able to run edge on IE mode, the answer is yes. But with selenium, no. The browser doesn't launch at all.